# Extract compound data from SDF file using IDNUMBER and write to a new file

Tags: bash, awk, chemistry

I'm still quite new to awk and have been trying to use a bash script and awk to filter a file according to a list of codes in a separate text file. While there are a few similar questions around, I have been unable to adapt their implementations.

My first file `idnumber.txt`looks like this:

```
4323-7584
K8933-4943
L2837-0493
```

The file I am attempting to filter the molecule blocks from has entries as follows:

```
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (K784-9550)
K784-9550

$$$$
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (4323-7584)
4323-7584

$$$$
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (4323-7584)
L2789-0943

$$$$
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (4323-2738)
4323-2738

> <SALT>
NaCl

$$$$
```

The file repeats in this fashion, starting with the `-ISIS- -- StrEd --` and ending with the `$$$$`. I need to extract this entire block for each string in IDNUMBER. So the expected output would be the block from above from -ISIS- to the $$$$ that has a matching ID in the IDNUMBER.txt.
Each entry is a different length, and I am trying to extract the entire block from the `-ISIS- -- StrEd --`

I have tried a few options of `sed` trying to recognise the first line to the IDNUMBER and extracting around it but that didn't work. My current iteration of the code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat idnumbers.txt | while read line
do
  sed -n '/^-ISIS-$/,/^$line$/p' compound_library.sdf > filtered.sdf
done
```

The logic behind what I was attempting was to find the block that would match the start as the ISIS phrase and end with the relevant ID number, copying that to a file. I realise now that what my logic was doing would skip the $$$$ that terminates each block.
But I have a feeling I am missing something as it is not actually writing anything to `filtered.sdf`.

Expected output:

```
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (4323-7584)
4323-7584

$$$$
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd -- 

 28 29  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.7382    0.7650    0.0000 C   0  0  0  
18 27  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <IDNUMBER> (4323-7584)
L2789-0943

$$$$
```

Edit:
So I have tried a different approach based on another question but have not been able to figure out how to alter the key assigned to a record in awk based on recognizing the characters at the line containing the IDNUMBER because it is a different field for each record.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\$\\$\\$\\$"; ORS="$$$$"}
     (NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}
     ($1 in a) { print a[$1] }' file1.sdf RS="\n" file2.txt
```

I assume it would be a matter of changing the field reference in the array `$1` to an expression that recognizes the line after `> <IDNUMBER>(xyz)`, but I am unsure how to go about achieving that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention sample output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Also if you could explain logic of getting expected output in your question that will make your question more clear, cheers.

Comment: If you want help extracting individual blocks from a file containing multiple blocks, then show a file containing multiple blocks as your sample input (as what separates the blocks is just as important as what they contain) and add the expected output. So, [edit] your question to show 4 or 5 blocks, some of which you want printed and some you don't, but obviously don't show 50 lines or whatever that is per block, reduce it to, say, 5.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've tried to clarify as per the questions you've asked.

Comment: @EdMorton fixed the points.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for, some explanation:

`[[:blank:]]` -> Space or tab only, not newline characters

First regex is looking for the start pattern `-ISIS- -- StrEd --` you mentioned (with a variable length of spaces/tabs between), and if it's a match, the variable `found` is set to 1

Second regex is looking for the end pattern `>  <IDNUMBER> (xxxx-xxxx)` (also with a variable length of spaces/tabs), where `xxxx-xxxx` is coming from the file `idnumber.txt`, and if it's a match set `found` to 2.
So now we know we are between the desired start and end of "idnumber"-text we want to print

Third regex is looking for `$$$$` and set `found` to 3 if matching.
This is the "real" endpoint, so jump with `exit` to the `END` section

So if the value of `found` is less or equal 2 the input line of `compound_library.sdf` is saved to variable `text`

At the `END` block of the awk the value of `found` is checked for the value 3 so the whole variable `text` is printed

```
while IFS= read IdNumber; do
  awk '
    BEGIN {
      found=0
      }
    /^[[:blank:]]*-ISIS-[[:blank:]]*--[[:blank:]]*StrEd[[:blank:]]*--/ {
      found=1
      }
    /^>[[:blank:]]*<IDNUMBER>[[:blank:]]*\('"${IdNumber}"'\)/ {
      found++
      #print "IdNumber='"${IdNumber}"', found=" found >>"/dev/stderr"
      }
    found <= 2 {
      text=sprintf("%s%s\n", text, $0)
      }
    /^\$\$\$\$$/ {
      found++
      exit
      }
    END {
      if (found == 3) {
        printf text
        }
      }' \
  compound_library.sdf
  #compound_library.sdf > ${IdNumber}.sdf
done < idnumber.txt
```

Comment: Calling awk in a shell loop is very rarely the right approach, it's not necessary for a problem like this where a single awk script could do the job orders of magnitude faster. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) and [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1745001) and [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1745001) for more on ways to improve your script.

Comment: Is it unwise to use awk in a shell loop due to efficiency?

Comment: Thanks gniemetz for the attempt, just have a few questions. So with the ```[[:sapce:]]``` does it go for only a single space or does it register for all whitespace between them?
I've also tried having a look for the ```found ==``` that you called several times, what does that actually call/do? 
The end of the block is ```$$$$```, how would that be implemented in the awk command?

Comment: @protein_fashion efficiency, robustness, clarity, portability, etc. as stated in that first link I referenced.

Comment: btw to notify someone you left a comment for them add their name preceded by @ otherwise they won't necessarily know.

Answer (score 0):

> I am missing something

In this command

```
sed -n '/^-ISIS-$/,/^$line$/p' compound_library.sdf > filtered.sdf
```

you are using following regular expressions

- `^-ISIS-$`
- `^$line$`

`^` denotes start of line, `$` denotes end of line

1st is looking for `-ISIS-` *spanning whole line*, whilst your file has

```
  -ISIS-  -- StrEd --
```

that is `-ISIS-` as part of line, therefore you should use regular expression without anchors that is `-ISIS-`

2nd does include `$` and then some other characters (`line`) implying some character being after end, which is impossible, so your code will keeping `p`rinting until all file is made, I have not idea if this is desired behavior, but be warned that more common way to do so in GNU `sed` is using `$` as address (meaning last line) for example if you want to print first line holding digit and all following you could do

```
sed -n '/[0-9]/,$p' file.txt
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks for clarifying that for me. I had been using $line to call from the while loop of line. The idea was that I would loop through the file.txt of all the ID numbers and at each loop would run the sed command but I am thinking now that is not the correct logic.

Comment: you're right, that is not the correct logic.